# Ubuntu auto-install sh script, how to pass apt-get or other commands answers to config options?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, apt-get

For instance, when installing MySQL I would like to automatically run some commands and answer a few questions:

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
Enter current password for root (enter for none): Type root password
Change the root password? N
Remove anonymous users? Y
Disallow root login remotely? Y
Remove test database and access to it? Y
Reload privilege tables now? Y
```

I want to make a script that installs and automatically provides the answers to the configuration questions.  How can I pass the MySQL configuration routine values based on set variables?

Edit[2015/04/18]:

Found a way:

```
echo -e "\npassword1\ny\npassword2\npassword2\ny\ny\ny\ny" | sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Its a bit messy but works, but i think hek2mgl answer is more readable.

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" to the title. You indicated that problem has been solved by accepting an answer.

Comment: Ok sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the answer into the command's stdin:

```
# Generate password somehow
password="$(pwgen -S)"

# Pass input to the installer using a here-document
sudo mysql_secure_installation <<EOF
$password
N
Y
Y
Y
Y
EOF
```